# Inverting a key/value pair

Tags: python, list, dictionary, counter

I've written the following code:

```
from collections import Counter

shopping_list = input().split()
a = Counter(shopping_list)

print('\n'.join("{} {}".format(k, v) for k, v in a.items()))
```

If the input is `carrots carrots bread tomatoes onions apples tomatoes carrots tomatoes onions onions onions bread milk bread apples`

The code outputs:

```
carrots 3
bread 3
tomatoes 3
onions 4
apples 2
milk 1
```

The code works fine, but any pairs that are inserted in the input have to be printed with the counter before the items themselves. (The test environment will insert different inputs each time)

So how do I make it output like this?

```
3 carrots
3 bread
3 tomatoes
4 onions
2 apples
1 milk
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: just change `.format(k, v) ` to `.format(v, k) `

Comment: doesn't inverting the format(k,v) to format(v, k) just invert it?

Comment: Yes, it does @TharakaDevinda

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @oskros

Final code with the modification proposed:

```
from collections import Counter

shopping_list = input().split()
a = Counter(shopping_list)

print('\n'.join("{} {}".format(v, k) for k, v in a.items()))
```